# JSF page returning null values

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page in my application to send an email with the details of the user to be included in the body.

The email is sent correctly but the values returned by the JSF are null and I can't figure out why.
Framework : Eclipse Kepler,JSF2, Glassfish4.
This the bean code

```
                  import java.util.Date;
                  import java.util.Properties;
                  import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
                  import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
                  import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
                 import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
                 import javax.inject.Named;
                 import javax.mail.Authenticator;
                 import javax.mail.Message;
                 import javax.mail.MessagingException;
                 import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
           import javax.mail.Session;
            import javax.mail.Transport;
            import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
             import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

              @ManagedBean
              @SessionScoped
             public class SendMail implements java.io.Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String to = "hamida.12@hotmail.fr";
private String objet = "Compte  inaccessible";
private String body= "Mon compte "
        + getNom()
        + " "
        + getPrenom()
        + " n'est plus accessible.Veuillez s'il vous plaît réinitialiser mes cordonnées et les envoyer à mon email "
        + getFrom();
```

The values i need to get from the jsf page are from,nom, prenom and i already created their getters and setters. and this is the jsf page code

```
                  <div id="box" style="height: 197px;">

        <h:form id="f1">
            <br></br>
            <div class="centre">
                <p:inputText placeholder="Nom" required="true" id="nom"
                    value="#{sendMail.nom}"
                    validator="#{AdministrateurBean.checkAdmin}"></p:inputText>
                <h:messages style="color:red" for="nom"/>
            </div>
            <div class="centre">
                <p:inputText placeholder="Prénom" required="true"
                    value="#{sendMail.prenom}" id="prenom" ></p:inputText>
                <h:messages style="color:red" for="prenom"/>
            </div>

            <div class="centre">
                <p:inputText placeholder="xyz@exemple.com" required="true" id="email"></p:inputText>
                <h:messages style="color:red" for="email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="centre">
                <p:commandButton value="Envoyer" size="30" style="width:207px"
                    action="#{sendMail.send}" update="f1" ></p:commandButton>
            </div>

        </h:form>
    </div>
```

And this is my web.xml code

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
             <display-name>Portail</display-name>
              <welcome-file-list>
              <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
              </welcome-file-list>
             <context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
           <param-value>delta</param-value>
          </context-param>
           <!-- keys gotten from recaptcha -->
          <context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
            <param-value>6Ld7pMESAAAAAHd1VihJkqPUXAJVwU3Cghc8fzrq</param-value>
          </context-param>

              <context-param>
             <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
              <param-value>6Ld7pMESAAAAAMhr5WSk5bcRrff8Y08NtDi8Buoq</param-value>
           </context-param>
               <servlet>
             <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
             <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
             </servlet>
           <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
               <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>

         </web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure, what you mean with "values returned from JSF". I think you mean the body String variable. You are creating variable when your backing bean is created. At that time all your members are null. You need to construct your body in the action method of the command button. At that time your members will be populated by the JSF framework.